# Doctrine2 Batch Insert

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to insert several entities to DB with a single query?
When I use an example from [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html) I can see several queries in the Web Debugger

UPDATED 23.08.2012

I found the following related links. I hope it will help to someone to understand a batch processing:

1. http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html
2. [doctrine2 - How to improve flush efficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707486/doctrine2-how-to-improve-flush-efficiency)
3. [Doctrine 2: weird behavior while batch processing inserts of entities that reference other entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431794/doctrine-2-weird-behavior-while-batch-processing-inserts-of-entities-that-refer)

The main things:

> Some people seem to be wondering why Doctrine does not use
>   multi-inserts (insert into (...) values (...), (...), (...), ...
>
> First of all, this syntax is only supported on mysql and newer postgresql versions. Secondly, there is no easy way to get hold of all
>   the generated identifiers in such a multi-insert when using
>   AUTO_INCREMENT or SERIAL and an ORM needs the identifiers for identity
>   management of the objects. Lastly, insert performance is rarely the
>   bottleneck of an ORM. Normal inserts are more than fast enough for
>   most situations and if you really want to do fast bulk inserts, then a
>   multi-insert is not the best way anyway, i.e. Postgres COPY or Mysql
>   LOAD DATA INFILE are several orders of magnitude faster.
>
> These are the reasons why it is not worth the effort to implement an abstraction that performs multi-inserts on mysql and postgresql in
>   an ORM.
>        I hope that clears up some questionmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there will be several insert statements, but only one query to the database per "flush" call.

As mentioned here
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html

Each "persist" will add an operation to the current UnitOfWork, then it is the call to EntityManager#flush() which will actually write to the database (encapsulating all the operation of the UnitOfWork in a single transaction).

But I have not checked that the behavior I describe above is the actual behavior.

Best regards,
Christophe

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm not sure that `only one query to the database per "flush" call`, because I can see a time of execution for each INSERT statement. It means that each INSERT statement is one query to DB. I updated my question