# Doctrine - improve insert data to pivot table

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have three tables:

Tag (entity) > tags_articles (pivot) < articles (entity)

Entity "article" has method "addTag(tag)"

If I need to add tags to article I do foreach loop:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $article->add($tag)
}

$this->em->flush()
```

Sometimes in that loop I need to add over 5000 tags. So all that script takes quite long, around 25s.

Is there any way to speed up that inserts to pivot table?

Thank you.

Comment: Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654530/doctrine2-multiple-insert-in-one-shot)

Comment: @KostasKolovos I know how to do multiple insert new objects. But I ask about inserts in to pivot table. Where we don't have pivot entity.